# new ViewController is not displaying when pushed in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, swift5

Here is my code to present a ViewController from app delegate in swift 5, I have done everything the same as everyOne else But the new ViewController is not shown when app is launched.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let welcome  = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as! WelcomeScreen

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = welcome
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
 return true
}
```

Comment: Where did you put this code?

Comment: in  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {} I edited the question.

Comment: Need to return true

Comment: I return true as well.

Comment: If you create a project in Xcode 11 / iOS 13 all that code needs to be moved into the scene delegate. Or else you need to remove scene support from your app.

Comment: Thank you I put in scene delegate and worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let welcome  = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as! WelcomeScreen
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = welcome
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If it is not working try:

```
 if let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main){
      if let welcome  = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as! WelcomeScreen{
           //Does it come here?
           self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
           self.window?.rootViewController = welcome
           self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()        
     }
 }
```

Make sure you actually get in to the body if most inner `if` which is `if  let welcome  = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Welcome") as! WelcomeScreen`

Comment: This is where the code was, I forgot to write the function. I edited the question .